# RDP Issue on Server 2003DC

Tags: windows-server-2003, rdp

I have a domain controller running 2003 32bit standard, for some reason RDP has just stopped working to this machine.  I have checked the firewall, the RDP service even symantec endpoint(note even turned endpoint off briefly to test).  All seem to be working normally and allowing access.

When i try to do an RDP session to the DC all i get is the Error "this computer cannot connect to the remote computer"

I have tried to telnet to port 3389 and that works without issue.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Anything in the event logs?

Comment: How about a reboot?

Comment: Tried a reboot no luck, nothing in the event log either.

Comment: Firewall issue?  Have you double-checked any firewalls between machines?

Comment: Have you tried connecting from a different PC to eliminate the PC you're using as the source of the problem?

Comment: Hi @Dave, welcome to the site.  @Coding Gorilla, this problem happens from multiple computers (ie mine and @Dave's).

Answer (score 1):

What do the event logs say?  What is the status of the Terminal Services Service?  Have you tried bouncing the Terminal Services Service?

Start up a MMC running under an account that is an admin of that server by using `runas /user:domain\adminuser mmc`, and then add either the Services or the Computer Management mmc, and connect to the remote computer as opposed to localhost

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this issue before on servers that run Routing & Remote Access (RRAS).

Other than that it might be a GPO setting that's being applied. Have you recently deployed any new GPO's?

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this same issue randomly (although more often after patches are installed).

What I've done to resolve it is:

1. Go into the Console and turn off remote desktop
2. **Reboot** the server
3. Go into the console and turn on Remote desktop

I've never been able to track down the why, but in a situation like you are describing that fixes it every time.

Comment: +1  It's frustrating that two decades into the Internet Age, things are still remedied with a reboot, but hey, it works.

Comment: @Andy yep, the really weird part is a reboot with RDP on does *not* fix it ... you've gotta turn rdp off then reboot